# What Holiday are you celebrating?

Tags: knowledge

In the morning of 2030, as you wake up, you remember it is a special day. Uh oh, what special day was it again? It seems you have forgotten, so you go downstairs to see if you can remember. You see your sister eating a strange sandwich dipped in sauce. She offers you one, but as you eat it, your remember that it is not a sandwich, but... you forgot what it was called. What was it again? The child of trash? You suddenly notice that your sister has adopted eight pet dogs. It is time to go to work, but your sister has replaced all of your normal suits with something that looks like a kimono, although you are sure it is not Japanese. You wear it and go to work, but notice that all of your co-workers have also adopted dogs. When your work is finally over, the boss surprises you all (Well only you, everyone else expected it) by giving you an extra check! As you drive back home, you see a sign, and laugh at yourself for forgetting.

What holiday is it?
Where do you live?
What month is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are

> the 2nd of February, 2030. This is the Chinese New Year.

On a special day, as you wake up, you remember it is a special day. Uh oh, what special day was it again? It seems you have forgotten, so you go downstairs to see if you can remember. You see your sister eating a strange sandwich dipped in sauce. She offers you one, but as you eat it, your remember that it is not a sandwich, but... you forgot what it was called. What was it again? The child of trash?

> <s>Probably Chinese Spring rolls. Bean sprouts maybe? (bin-sprouts)</s> That is dumplings.

You suddenly notice that your sister has adopted eight pet dogs.

> 2030 is the Year of the Dog

It is time to go to work, but your sister has replaced all of your normal suits with something that looks like a kimono.

> You usually buy new clothing on Chinese New Year. Maybe a Tang Suit?

You wear it and go to work, but notice that all of your co-workers have also adopted dogs.

> 2030 is the Year of the Dog

When your work is finally over, the boss surprises you all (Well only you, everyone else expected it) by giving you an extra check!

> <s>Probably a bonus for your last year's work</s> Must be the Chinese red envelope that is offered on that particular day

As you drive back home, you see a sign, and laugh at yourself for forgetting.

> Probably a sign indicating that a street is blocked due to the New Year parade

Answer (score 1):

Would it be

> [Shōgatsu, the Japanese New Year in Japan, January 1st](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_New_Year)

You see your sister eating a strange sandwich dipped in sauce. She offers you one, but as you eat it, your remember that it is not a sandwich, but... you forgot what it was called. What was it again? The child of trash?

> The first thing to come to mind was takoyaki or dango, as those are both things that have sauce drizzled on them. But "child of trash" must be a reference to the name of a type of food... perhaps a type of dumpling? Those are often dipped in sauces. The only other thing I can think of that doesn't sound appetizing is rice gruel.

You suddenly notice that your sister has adopted eight pet dogs. It is time to go to work, but your sister has replaced all of your normal suits with something that looks like a kimono. You wear it and go to work, but notice that all of your co-workers have also adopted dogs.

> "dogs" could refer to "hot dogs", which are miniature weiners cut to look like an octopus and can be found in bento, which is traditionally eaten for the first three days of the year. Eight is also a lucky number, so many things revolve around it. There may be a different reference here I'm not getting. The kimono reference makes me think it is some sort of Japanese holiday.

When your work is finally over, the boss surprises you all (Well only you, everyone else expected it) by giving you an extra check!

> There are "lucky bags" with money or other goodies in it. This is usually customary of people who are either related or have a very good relationship with one another. Good for you, getting along with your boss!